# How to mock DataReader to unit test DAL

Tags: c#

I have a method in my data access layer that performs mapping.  The method accepts a DataReader, and maps the data to the proper domain object properties.  Is there a good way to somehow mock the DataReader so I can perform unit tests on the mapping methods without hitting against a physical database?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Lucky for you, `DataReader` implements the `IDataReader` interface.

Instead of relying on a `DataReader` in your code, use `IDataReader`. Then, in your tests you can substitute your own implementation that returns dummy data, or use a mocking framework like [Rhino.Mocks](http://www.ayende.com/projects/rhino-mocks.aspx) or similar to create the stubs and assign return values.

Depending on how you're "getting" the `DataReader` in your code, you may need to do a little refactoring. What you want is to have external dependencies like this "injected" in the constructor (preferred) or through a property, so that consumers of the class can substitute any implementation of `IDataReader`. (This substitution is also why you declare your parameters/properties as abstractions rather than concrete types.) This is known as [Dependency Injection](http://www.codeproject.com/KB/architecture/DependencyInjection.aspx), a form of [Inversion of Control](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff647976.aspx).

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to mock the IDataReader to return a list of records, you can create a class that implements IDataReader and override some of its methods (like Read() and Indexer). Also, you would need a variable to keep record of current row and a variable to hold the list values. Below is the sample code for doing this:

```
public class MockDataReader : IDataReader
{
    private int _rowCounter = 0;
    private List<Dictionary<string,object>> _records = new List<Dictionary<string,object>>();

    public MockDataReader(List<Dictionary<string,object>> records)
    {
        _records = records;
    }

    public bool Read()
    {
        _rowCounter++;
        if (_rowCounter < _records.Count) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public object this[string name]
    {
        get { return _records[_rowCounter][name]; }
    }
}
```

Then to make use of this class, you can use the following code:

```
var itemsList = new List<Dictionary<string, object>>();
for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
{
    var num = i + 1;
    var items = new Dictionary<string, object>();
    items.Add("Id", num);
    items.Add("FirstName", "MyFirstName" + num);
    items.Add("LastName", "MyLastName" + num);
    itemsList.Add(items);
}


var result = new MockDataReader(itemsList);
```

Not a full proof way but works. Hope it helps :)

Comment: I wouldn't create the actual class to mock `IDataReader`, but +1 for showing what you need to set your mock object up to implement.

Comment: There is a problem with this code if my list has only one item.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, don't use `DataReader` but [IDataReader](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatareader.aspx) or [IDataRecord](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.idatarecord.aspx), then mock whatever you want.